# Prevent accelerator from triggering while typing in child

Tags: java, swing

```
package dadjf;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;





public class Test extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    JPopupMenu popupMenu;


    public static void main(String [] args){
        Test test = new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

         JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();


         // Options Menu
         JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
         optionsMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
         optionsMenu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Options Menu");
         menuBar.add(optionsMenu);

         JMenuItem broadenMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Broaden Parent Search", false);
         broadenMenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("B"));
         broadenMenuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Broadens the parent search");
         optionsMenu.add(broadenMenuItem);
         this.add(menuBar, "dock north");
         popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
         final JMenu firstSubmenu= new JMenu("First Submenu");
         final JMenu secondSubmenu= new JMenu("Second Submenu");


         JTextField firstTextField = new JTextField(30);
         JTextField secondTextField = new JTextField(30);
         firstSubmenu.add(firstTextField);
         secondSubmenu.add(secondTextField);


        popupMenu.add(firstSubmenu);
        popupMenu.add(secondSubmenu);

        jframe.add(this);
        this.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        this.add(popupMenu);


        this.add(new JTextField(30));
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {

            popupMenu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());

    }

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

I want it to be such that if I right click and start typing into the submenu textfield, if I type a 'b' into the field, it doesn't immediately close the popup and trigger the checkbox.

In my actual code I've got ~10 accelerators, so I'd like to know a solution that I can apply generically and not not need to hardcode 10 separate interruptors.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when you ask a question. We can't test your code to se the behaviour. That is post minimal executable code that demonstrates the problem. The code snippet above is not compilable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I modified it.

Comment: `In my actual code I've got ~10 accelerators, so I'd like to know a solution that I can apply generically` - don't use JTextField in the menu? When you have weird design you have weird problems. Also accelerators aren't the problem since you invoke an accelerator with the Alt key (on Windows). The mnemonics are the problem since you just type the character underlined in the menu item.

Comment: The accelerator in my example is triggering on B with no alt key being held.

Having text fields in a popup menu is necessary, unfortunately. The user needs to be able to highlight specific objects and modify parameters using text fields.

Comment: Sorry (my mistake), typically for a mnemonic you use Alt to invoke the menu and then the character to invoke the item. The item can only ever be invoked when the menubar/menu has focus. For accelerators you would typically use Ctrl+B to have direct access to the Action of the item. So the problem you are having is that you are NOT following standard GUI design practices. So the simple solution is to follow standards and don't use a single character as the accelerator. If you don't want to follow standards then you need to do exception coding as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Also you should not be adding a JMenuBar to a JPanel. You should be using the `setJMenuBar(...)` method of the frame. Maybe start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make it such that when I'm typing into this popup, the accelerators aren't triggered?

Accelerators and mnemonics use `Key Bindings` to map a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. These bindings can invoke an Action even if the component doesn't have focus, which is the case for menus.

> Is there some sort of listener I can add to the textfields?

You can add your own key bindings to the text fields. That is key bindings for a component that has focus will take precedence over the key bindings of the menu.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information and examples.

You will need to do a separate binding for each character that is used as a mnemonic. I don't know if you can just create a dummy Action that does nothing (so the default behaviour of the text field can be used) or whether you will actually need to insert the character into the text field yourself.

Comment: To make this solution generalizable, I used a BFS on the JMenuBar, finding all accelerator keys, and add a keybinding that does nothing for all of those keys.